# How do I put two text fields side by side on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I have a flutter form where the user will enter his card details. I want it to look exactly like in the picture below

[image]

I already know how to put the 'Number' and 'Card Holder' text fields. How do I put the Expiry Date and CVV text fields side by side like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Row widget and put these two text widgets as children.

Example

```
Row(
     children: [
          Text( 'Expired Date'),
          Text('CVV'),
              ],
   ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple row widget is used for side by side container
Column widget is used for side under side

Row(
Children [

Container (Text(’row 1’),

Container (Text(’row 1’)

],
);